# Openrewrite exclude class/method from replacing

Tags: java, openrewrite

I recently started using the openrewrite and wanted to know if there is any way we can exclude a class or method from replacing with a any recipe. I have some unit test that is specifically used to test maps with null key uisng `Collections.singletonMap`. While I run the `org.openrewrite.java.migrate.UpgradeToJava17` recipe it uses `Map.of` and my tests start failing as Map.of cannot take `null` keys.

Answer (score 1):

The Collections.singletonMap recipes that you mention have been [removed from the default Java 8 to 11 migration recipe](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-migrate-java/pull/253), precisely because of the issues you mentioned. You can upgrade to [rewrite-migrate-java version 2.0.7](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-migrate-java/releases/tag/v2.0.7) such that you won't need any exclusions.

If you would still want to use exclusions, you can do so with [the `exclusions` option in the Maven plugin](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/rewrite-maven-plugin#plugin-configuration), or [similar for Gradle](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/gradle-plugin-configuration#configuring-the-rewrite-dsl).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I actually like the `Collections.singetonMap` to `Map.of` However wanted to disable only 1 method. I will move that to a different class and exclude that class using exclude option. This is just a workaround. I would recommend having some annotations at method level like @IgnoreRewrite  to give flexibility

Comment: You can still directly run that recipe apply those changes; it's just no longer part of the default Java 8 to 11 (and 11 to 17) migration until those issues are resolved.

Comment: And I like your suggestion of `@IgnoreRewrite`, but I'd rather have the recipes in such a state that you do not have to add exclusions either on recipes or on files/code. There should be no reason for you to have to inspect the results, ideally, as a lot of people run these recipes not on a single project but on dozens at a time.